# Issue with counting word occurrence for multiple words

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

the issue that I'm having is that I'm not exactly sure how to reset my word count. I created a word search, but when I have it count the number of occurrence of 10 different words, it stays the same number from the first word it counts. I believe the problem I'm having is where I use a `for` loop

Output

```
boy appeared 3 times
Snape appeared 3 times
Dumbledore appeared 3 times
he appeared 3 times
her appeared 3 times
the appeared 3 times
it appeared 3 times
is appeared 3 times
will appeared 3 times
all appeared 3 times
```

What it should look like

```
boy appeared 3 times
Snape appeared 7 times
Dumbledore appeared 4 times
he appeared 27 times
her appeared 4 times
the appeared 13 times
it appeared 6 times
is appeared 12 times
will appeared 2 times
all appeared 3 times
```

By reading my codes I'm sure I've made it more complicated than it is. I would appreciate any advice and corrections that I've made.

Full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// Main Function
int main()
{
    // Declaration
    std::string list, passage, word[10];
    std::ifstream listFile("WordList.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::ifstream passageFile("HarryPotterPassage.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::vector<std::string> vec_wordList, vec_passage;


    /* Read a file that contains a list of 10 words */
    if (listFile.is_open())
    {
        // Store text file in a vector
        while (listFile)
        {
            listFile >> list;
            vec_wordList.push_back(list);
        }

        // Assign vector to individual strings
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            word[i] = vec_wordList[i];
        }

        // Close file
        listFile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No file found.\n";


    /* Read another file containing a paragraph */
    if (passageFile.is_open())
    {
        while (passageFile)
        {
            // Store text file in a string
            std::getline(passageFile, passage);
        }

        // Close file
        passageFile.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No file found.\n";

    //std::cout << passage << '\n';


    /* Count the number of words from the first file
       from the second file that contains the paragraph */
    size_t count = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        while ((pos = passage.find(word[i], pos)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            count++;
            pos += word[i].size();
        }

        std::cout << word[i] << " appeared " << count << " many times\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be probably easier to solve using a `std::unoredered_map<std::string,int>`.

Comment: I think that you need to set `count = 0` and `pos = 0` at the beginning of every iteration of the `for` loop. Basically, you can just move those two declarations **into** that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `count` and `pos` at the beginning of every iteration of the outer loop.

In other words, change this:

```
size_t count = 0;
std::string::size_type pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    ...
}
```

BTW, I'd also change that `10` to `sizeof(word)/sizeof(*word)`.

Comment: And if you're on C++11 or higher, then I'd even use `for (const auto& w : word)`, and replace every `word[i]` inside the loop with `w`.

Comment: Wow! I knew it was something so simple. Been giving me a headache for 24 hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't reset. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @gomicoo: No problem. BTW, I didn't even bother to test my solution. It was obvious to me that you needed a different `count` for each `word[i]`, and from there I concluded that you also needed a different `pos` for each `word[i]`. Please note the additional fix suggested in the comment above.

Comment: I've never used that way of a for loop. I'll have to research how else I could use it for future reference.

Comment: @gomicoo: In any case, try to refrain from using that constant value of `10`.

Comment: thanks again. I actually did try using sizeof(word) but it crashed. any particular reason sizeof(word) works if its divided by a pointer of sizeof(word)

Comment: @gomicoo: `sizeof(word)/sizeof(*word)` is not "dividing by a pointer" (there's no such thing as "dividing by a pointer" anyway). `sizeof(word)` denotes the total number of `char`s in the `word` array. `sizeof(*word)` denotes the total number of `char`s in a single element in the `word` array. Hence dividing the former by the latter gives the number of elements in the `word` array, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You use word[9] instead of word[i], so you get the results of the last word instead of each one.
try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    while ((pos = passage.find(word[i], pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        count++;
        pos += word[i].size();
    }

    std::cout << word[i] << " appeared " << count << " many times\n";
}
```

Comment: Darn it, I forgot to change it. That's how I originally have it using word[i]. I was changing the numbers so I know what results it's actually suppose to be. Changing it to word[i] does not work for me either.